# Apache CXF does not log SOAP messages with log4j2

Tags: logging, cxf, log4j2, cxf-client

I'm using Apache CXF 3.1 for a SOAP client. My intend is to log all incoming and outgoing SOAP messages to a logfile with log4j2. This is my current setup:

The SOAP client is implemented using a `JaxWsProxyFactoryBean`.

I placed a file `org.apache.cxf.Logger` in the directory `src/META-INF/cxf` with content `org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger`

**cxf.xml:**

```
<bean id="loggingFeature" class="org.apache.cxf.feature.LoggingFeature">
    <property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />
</bean>
<cxf:bus>
    <cxf:features>
        <ref bean="loggingFeature" />
    </cxf:features>
</cxf:bus>
```

**log4j2.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="CONSOLE" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%t] %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>
        <File name="LOG_FILE" fileName="all.log" immediateFlush="false" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level [%t] %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="DEBUG">
            <AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="LOG_FILE"/>
        </Root>
        <Logger name="org.apache.cxf" level="INFO">
            <AppenderRef ref="LOG_FILE" />
        </Logger>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

However I cannot see any CXF log messages in the file. What am I missing here?

Comment: try adding `<property name="prettyLogging" value="true" />` for logging feature bean, and setting `org.apache.cxf` logger to info

Comment: @Isukthar Thanks for the hint. I updated the description based on your comment. Unfortunately still no SOAP calls are logged to the file but only to the console.

Comment: `src/META-INF/cxf` is in the classpath? Have you tried to use the system variable `-Dorg.apache.cxf.Logger=org.apache.cxf.common.logging.Log4jLogger`

Comment: @pedrofb Yes, `src/META-INF/cxf` is in the classpath as far as I can tell. Using the system variable does not have any effect either.

Comment: Doesn't apache cxf use slf4j to log ? If so you can try adding log4j-slf4j-impl to the class path. Log4j 2 SLF4J Binding allows applications coded to the SLF4J API to use Log4j 2 as the implementation. https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-slf4j-impl/index.html